# Log rotation is not working automatically

Tags: cron, logrotate

Trying to create log rotation, but it's not working automatically.

write following code in .sh file and store in `/etc/logratate.d/xxx`:

```
/var/log/xxx/*.log {
  daily
  missingok
  rotate 10
  compress
  delaycompress
  notifempty
  copytruncate
}
```

it doesn't rotate each day, but if run `/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf`, log rotation work well. I googled it said cron is not running, so I run `sudo /usr/sbin/cron start`, it still not working.

Comment: I'm curious on how Google said cron is not running... You may want to share the command you actually run and its output. Look at the output of `grep -r logrotate /etc/cron*` for more info on your `cron` jobs.